# Pytorch model runtime error when testing U-Net

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've defined a U-Net model using Pytorch but it won't accept my input. I've checked the model layers and they seem to be applying the operations as I would expect them to but I still get an error.

I've just switched to Pytorch after mostly using Keras so I'm not really sure how to debug this issue, the error I get is:

> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 64, 3, 3], expected
> input[1, 128, 65, 65] to have 64 channels, but got 128 channels
> instead

Here's the code I'm using:

```
class UNET(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=2, out_channels=2):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = self.contract_block(in_channels, 32, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = self.contract_block(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.conv3 = self.contract_block(64, 128, 3, 1)

        self.upconv3 = self.expand_block(128, 64, 3, 1)
        self.upconv2 = self.expand_block(64, 32, 3, 1)
        self.upconv1 = self.expand_block(32, out_channels, 3, 1)

    def __call__(self, x):

        # downsampling part
        conv1 = self.conv1(x)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)

        upconv3 = self.upconv3(conv3)

        upconv2 = self.upconv2(torch.cat([upconv3, conv2], 1))
        upconv1 = self.upconv1(torch.cat([upconv2, conv1], 1))

        return upconv1

    def contract_block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding):

        contract = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=1)
            )

        return contract

    def expand_block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding):

        expand = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            )
        return expand

model = UNET()
x = torch.randn(1, 2, 256, 256)
print(model(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the model layer definition.

You defined `self.upconv2 = self.expand_block(64, 32, 3, 1)` but what you do is concatenating 2 tensors each with **64** channels so in total you get **128**.

You should fix the channels of the up-sampling part of the U-Net to match the number of channels after the concatenation.

Doing the mentioned fix will give you:

```
class UNET(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=2, out_channels=2):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = self.contract_block(in_channels, 32, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = self.contract_block(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.conv3 = self.contract_block(64, 128, 3, 1)

        self.upconv3 = self.expand_block(128, 64, 3, 1)
        self.upconv2 = self.expand_block(64 + 64, 32, 3, 1)
        self.upconv1 = self.expand_block(32 + 32, out_channels, 3, 1)

    def __call__(self, x):

        # downsampling part
        conv1 = self.conv1(x)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)

        upconv3 = self.upconv3(conv3)
        upconv2 = self.upconv2(torch.cat([upconv3, conv2], 1))
        upconv1 = self.upconv1(torch.cat([upconv2, conv1], 1))

        return upconv1

    def contract_block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding):

        contract = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=1)
            )

        return contract

    def expand_block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding):

        expand = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=padding),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            )
        return expand

model = UNET()
x = torch.randn(1, 2, 256, 256)
print(model(x))
```

---

Based on the comment, if you have other spatial dimensions that might not fit the parameters of the convolutions operations you can do one of 2 options:

1. Start play with the parameter based on the formula at the bottom of the [`Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) so that you will match the input dimension.
2. You could force pad the target to desired dimension using the following 2 functions:

   ```
   import torch
   import torch.nn as nn
   import torch.nn.functional as F


   def pad_tensor(source, target):
       """
       Pad source tensor to match target tensor size

       :param source: tensor that need to get padding
       :param target: tensor of the desired shape
       :return: source tensor with shape equal to target
       """

       diff_y = target.size()[2] - source.size()[2]
       diff_x = target.size()[3] - source.size()[3]

       source = F.pad(source, [diff_x // 2, diff_x - diff_x // 2, diff_y // 2, diff_y - diff_y // 2])
       return source


   def concatenate_tensors(x1, x2):
       """
       Concatenate both tensors

       :param x1: first tensor to be concatenated
       :param x2: second tensor to be concatenated
       :return: concatenation of both tensors
       """

       x1 = pad_tensor(x1, x2)
       return torch.cat([x1, x2], dim=1)
   ```

Now call `concatenate_tensors` instead of `torch.cat` this will fix the dimensions to match the size you need.

Comment: Thanks! This now works but I wanted the output to be the same shape as the input. It's now (1, 2, 257, 257). Can you suggest a way to fix this?